# Use of "pull" in lieu of the phrasal verb "pull off"

Tags: formality, phrase-usage

Example: "pull a miracle" instead of "pull off a miracle".

A quick google search shows the former being used in sports contexts, though I have heard of it in informal conversation as well.

Is this usage grammatical? To contexts of what degree of formality may it be accepted?

Comment: In sports usage, I wonder if the origin for *pull a miracle* isn't only *pull off a miracle* but also *pull a miracle out of the bag/hat*. I can find several instances of both in cheesy sports writing.

Comment: [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/pull) gives a sense that might at least give the wrong sort of connotation to the expression: **pull** _verb_ (DISHONEST) [ T ] _slang_
to perform a dishonest action:
_The gang that pulled the bank robbery were all arrested. / 
No one's gonna pull that kind of trick on me!_